# vb.net : how to get result from cmd to textbox

Tags: vb.net, shell, cmd, textbox, command

i trying to run this command in cmd and get the result to my textbox4.text without success 
command : cscript  "%windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs" /xpr | findstr /S /M /I /C:"permanently"

result in need to get in my textbox4 : 
The machine is permanently activated.

i write this code without success :

```
    Dim qassam As String

    qassam = Shell("whoami")
    TextBox4.Text = CStr(qassam)
```

and also i found this but not working :

```
 Dim oProcess As New Process()
    Dim oStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "cscript %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs /xpr | findstr /S /M /I /C:permanently ")
    oStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    oStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    oProcess.StartInfo = oStartInfo
    oProcess.Start()

    Dim sOutput As String
    Using oStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = oProcess.StandardOutput
        sOutput = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
    End Using

    TextBox4.Text = sOutput   'txtOutput being the output textbox.
```

im new at vb.net i need simple code please to understand

Comment: Have you tried debugging? What errors, if any, are you getting?

Comment: i got no error i got an blank textbox

Comment: You need to look up debugging - put break points on your code and check the output at each point. That way you can find out what exactly isn't working (is it the stream, the process?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by just add this /k to 
("cmd.exe", "/c cscript %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs /xpr | findstr /S /M /I /C:permanently ")`

```
 Dim oProcess As New Process()
    Dim oStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", " /c cscript ""%windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs"" /xpr | findstr ""The machine""")
    oStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    oStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    oProcess.StartInfo = oStartInfo
    oProcess.Start()

    Dim sOutput As String
    Using oStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = oProcess.StandardOutput
        sOutput = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
    End Using

    TextBox4.Text = sOutput
```

Comment: I must be going blind, lol... I don't see where you added the /k to your solution? ;)